# Reflection reduction in image

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Lighting problems are common and difficult.  How does one detect and reduce light reflection to save more information from an image? I have tried several methods with OpenCV and Python without luck.

(Image with reflection)

[image: image with light reflection]

(Image without reflection)

[image: image without light reflection]

I tried converting to HSV color space, and apply Histogram Equalization to the V channel, with [Clahe](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/daf/tutorial_py_histogram_equalization.html) equalization:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('glare.png')

hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
h, s, v = cv2.split(hsv_image)

clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
v = clahe.apply(v)

hsv_image = cv2.merge([h, s, v])
hsv_image = cv2.cvtColor(hsv_image, cv2.COLOR_HSV2RGB)

cv2.imwrite('clahe_h.png', hsv_image)
```

results:

[image: image after clahe equalization]

As well I tried thresholding to find bright pixels and than use [Image Inpainting](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d3d/tutorial_py_inpainting.html) to replace them with neighbouring pixels.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('glare.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 225, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

dst_TELEA = cv2.inpaint(image,thresh,3,cv2.INPAINT_TELEA)
cv2.imwrite('after_INPAINT.png',dst_TELEA)
```

results:
(after threshold)
[image: after threshold]

[image: after inpainting]

Comment: [does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016797/what-can-i-do-for-eliminate-a-reflection-light-of-a-image-using-opencv)  They claim to use adaptive thresholding, [look here for example on using it](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Comment: You could probably do an edge detection. You will get significant edges on the _glass_. Then you can map the pixels inside the _edge boundary_ with the pixels outside. However, this would probably work only for this message. Also, try running CLAHE on all three channels

Comment: Thanks, I tried adaptive thresholding but it does not produce any good results. @Rick M. Thanks, I would like to know what is the most proper method to deal with light reflection problems not only this situation but thanks for answer I will try it and will post results.

Comment: Try using a threshold of 230 to 240, I tried it and it seems to detected the edges where you have the reflection perfectly. After this you could call inPaint. Most of the reflection/shadow removal methods I know of are edge-based methods. You might want to do some research on that.

Comment: In the first example you're converting the image with cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV. cv2.imread() outputs a BGR not RGB image. Anyway, did you find a solution eventually?

Comment: Could this be of some help? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470569/remove-glare-from-photo-opencv

Answer (score 2):

There's no **general** method for effective glare removal.

HSV + CLAHE is a good and common start, but industry methods "cheat" by assuming some information about the subject (human face, fruit on a conveyor belt, retina through an ophthalmoscope), and sometimes information about the lighting (white ceiling light with very sharp edges, for the images in this question).